# Why must MicroBatchReader be Serializable? Task not serializable error

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm practicing implementing my own V2 custom Structured Streaming Source in Java which just reads text from a socket and parses it into a JavaBean with two fields "field1" and "field2".

When running a SimpleQuery

```
StreamingQuery query = inStream.groupBy("field1").count().writeStream()
     .outputMode("complete")
     .format("console")
     .start();
```

I get the following error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
...

Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException: CustomStreamSource.SocketSourceV2$SocketBatchReader

Serialization stack:
...
```

I have a couple of instance variables which cannot be serialized in my custom SocketBatchReader, namely a `Socket` and a `Thread`. Is there anyway around this? Also, the source [socket batch reader implementation](https://github.com/hienluu/wikiedit-streaming/blob/master/streaming-receiver/src/main/scala/org/wikiedit/receiver/structured_streaming/WikiEditSourceV2.scala#L243) does not seem to implement `Serializable` either.

Comment: I am currently trying to write my own structured streaming source too. How did you implement the `createMicroBatchReader` function? The javadoc suggests to recover from hdfs checkpoint etc. Can you share your code? I can write an additional question if you like.

Comment: The socket source I'm implementing is an unreliable receiver so it does not implement checkpointing. But I'll still upload the code to github once I get a working solution -- still running into some bugs.

Comment: Thank you in advance... By the way, I wrote my problem as an extra [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684667/spark-structured-streaming-with-rabbitmq-source), would be glad if you could have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I had my class structure like this

```
public class ... implements DataSourceV2, ... {
    private class ... implements MicroBatchReader {

    }
}
```

Moving my MicroBatchReader outside of DataSourceV2 worked for me.

```
public class ... implements DataSourceV2, ... {

}
private class ... implements MicroBatchReader {

}
```